# How to transmit the data over serial on realtime continuously i.e without pressing enter?

Tags: serial-port, arduino

I need to send continuous data from my OpenCV program to Arduino. I have check my serial program separately.It works fine after I give the input and press enter. Now I need to transfer the data to Arduino continuously i.e without pressing enter.But does not work if I send the data under infinite loop. Do I have to keep any delay in my serial port program (like sleep())?

Comment: *"...I give the input and press enter"* -- That's because (presumably) you're using **canonical** input. (Can't tell if you mean you're typing input on a keyboard and that gets passed on to the serial port, or *"I give the input"* represents the program and *"press enter"* is '\n'.)  *"Do I have to keep any delay..."*  -- That depends on how fast the Arduino can accept data. (That is what **flow control** is for, instead of arbitrary delays.)  Also depends on whether the Arduino is setup for canonical input or non-canonical (aka raw)(data is binary and line termination is not expected).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. About two seconds should be enough. [Or read this.....](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/DisablingAutoResetOnSerialConnection)